# Остановка рекурсивной функции

Tags: c, строки, рекурсия

Пишу в Code::Blocks, на C. Перебираю все возможные варианты строк для произвольной заданной длины и сравниваю результат с образцовой строкой. Решил пойти через рекурсию, но столкнулся с проблемой. Даже когда моя функция уже подобрала нужную строку, ещё какое-то время выполняются оставшиеся вызовы этой функции, что занимает достаточно много времени. При этом мне необходим продолжить выполнение программы. Сначала реализовывал проверку с помощью глобальной переменной, но это очень плохая идея. Хотел бы узнать, есть ли способ лучше и проще.

```
char* constructor(char* p_p, char* t_p, short unsigned int lvl, char* symbols, short unsigned int border){
    if(lvl > strlen(t_p)){
        return p_p;
    }
    else{
        p_p[lvl-1] = ' ';
        p_p[lvl+1] = '\0';
        for(short unsigned int i =0; i<border; i++){
            p_p[lvl-1] = symbols[i];
            p_p = constructor(p_p, t_p, lvl+1, symbols, border);
            if(!strcmp(p_p, t_p)){
                printf_s("Password: %s\n", p_p);
            }
        }
        p_p[lvl - 1] = '\0';
        return p_p;
    }
};
```

Поясню про переменные: p_p - указатель на строку, с её помощью и перебираем все варианты; t_p - образцовая строка, с которой сравниваем; lvl - "уровень погружения", обозначает символ, который мы перебираем в данный момент; symbols - указатель на строку со всеми допустимыми символами; border - "граница" допустимых символов

Comment: А как определяется, что строка подобралась?

Comment: @Эникейщик, через strcmp

Comment: Т.е. когда печатается "Password: %s\n",  можно завершать цикл?

Comment: @Эникейщик, Да, всё верно. Когда пароль выведется на экран, можно завершать работу данной функции, но нужно продолжить работу программы

Comment: Если не хотите глобальную переменную, то тащите по всем вызовам адрес локальной, из контекста той внешней функции, что вызывает рекурсивную. В ней вы можете хранить некоторе состояние, анализ которого внутри рекурсивных вызовов меняет их ход

Answer (score 2):

Просто сразу возвращать найденное значение

```
if(!strcmp(p_p, t_p))
    { printf_s("Password: %s\n", p_p);
      return p_p;
    }
```

Comment: При таком варианте у меня надпись "Password: <Пароль>"  выводится по несколько раз, можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: А без такого варианта сколько раз выводится?

Comment: неправильно выразился. И при изначальном варианте и при вашем выводится по несколько раз. Притом, чем длиннее строка, тем больше раз надпись выводится

Comment: попробуйте перенести ``printf_s("Password: %s\n", p_p);`` перед ``return p_p;`` в ``if(lvl > strlen(t_p))``